# Stop JQuery slidedown being obliterated by another ajax event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I am doing a slide-down but another further `ajax` process from a module do a display none on that selector.

How can I stop this further process to happen?

```
    function openUpIndividualFacet(key) {
      var selector = 'div[id*="' + key + '"] i';          
      //i can see the block getting red before it got display none
$(selector).parent().parent().children('.block__content').css('background','red');                        
     $(selector).parent().parent().children('.block__content').slideDown();

    }
```

Comment: what part of the *code* you posted `$(selector).slideDown();` are you having an issue with - there's not much code there, had to see what you could've done wrong with it

Comment: @Bravo i have edited the code

Comment: I see nothing that sets display:none in the code

Comment: @Bravo when i inspect the DOM i see that another script from a drupal module is adding a display none

Comment: you can't change or delay that without editing that code